# JavaFX 11, How can I handle this error? java.lang.module.FindException

Tags: javafx

Whenever I create a JavaFX project from eclipse, I got compiling error as follows and don't know how to solve the issue:

```
Eclipse, widows10, Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

What I've done before I got this message: JavaFX 11 is installed, User library(JavaFX) is created and added to a project, Build path is configured, VM argument is added But I still get this error message.

I need to work on a project with JavaFX but this error stopped me from doing my job for several days.

I did exactly what is said in the link.

//openjfx.io/openjfx-docs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XJicRt_FaI&t=1365s

What seems to be the problem? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: _I did exactly what is said in the link_ which I doubt (no offense meant, but .. it would work if you did :) And note: most probably nobody is going to watch a video.

Comment: Try following other approaches detailed in the openjfx.io documentation you linked.  Do not install the JavaFX library SDK.  Do not try to manually configure the JavaFX libraries in your IDE.  Use JavaFX via a build tool, such as Maven or Gradle.  Auto-import the build tool project into your IDE, so that the IDE auto-configures the required dependencies.  It is possible to achieve what you have been trying using the library SDK, but there are other workable approaches that you should try if you have failed with the library installation approach for a few days.

Comment: I recommend using a more up-to-date version of JavaFX and the JDK e.g. 16+.  If you continue to have difficulty using Eclipse for JavaFX development after following the other recommendations, consider switching IDEs, e.g. to Intellij Idea Community Edition.

Comment: @jewelsea, A noob question. I always use the latest version of JavaFX, but should we? I thought the right course was to use the LTS version?

Comment: @Sedrick noob? nope ;-) Depends on what you are doing.  For common questions like this, where somebody is creating a new project and having environmental issues getting started, I'd always recommend at least trying the latest version.  If you have a large established project which was built a while back and tested on the LTS version, unless something really unexpectedly breaks, then no real reason to upgrade until the next LTS version is released.  If the project is currently being deployed to Java 8, I'd always recommend upgrading, regardless.

Comment: @jewelsea, relatively speaking, I am a noob compared to you and others that answer JavaFX questions on this site. LOL. The only thing I have dealt with that was labeled with LTS was Ubuntu. I always used the LTS version for that. I was always under the idea that the LTS version would receive any bug fixes but not upgrade. Upgrades would be added to the next LTS version. I never actually looked into LTS. This was just my thinking from reading about it on Ubuntu download page years ago. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Sedrick if interested you can find out more info about [LTS for JavaFX](https://gluonhq.com/services/javafx-support/) from the Gluon site (Gluon run the long term support for JavaFX).  For JavaFX 11, three years ago, it was the first release that really embraced modules 100% and separated JavaFX out from the JDK code-base as a modular system.  As a first release of the complete modular feature set, I guess there are likely issues with those features that were addressed more fully in later releases, even though JavaFX 11 has continued to receive bug fixes.